# "There is some evidence" or "there are some evidence"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I've read an article on BBC and the author wrote "*there is some evidence...*", but that phrase is really confusing because "*some*" is a plural identification but following "*is*". Can someone please explain this?

Comment: The word **some** can be used with mass nouns as well, and **evidence** is a mass noun. This mass noun is grammatically singular, that's why we use **is**. In English, "evidence" is viewed as "water" (from a grammar standpoint, not in the legal sense). The word is singular but the amount of evidence, or the amount of water, can range widely. "[There is some water in the pot](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65305/there-is-a-little-water-in-the-pot-there-is-some-water-in-the-pot)." ... "There is some evidence in the suitcase".

Answer (score 4):

According to [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/some), **some** can be used as a determiner, followed by an uncountable noun:

> I’ll make some coffee.

followed by a plural noun:

> She brought me some flowers.

followed by a singular countable noun, to refer to someone or something that is unknown or unspecified:

> She married some guy she met on the boat.